# Why is my functional test failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies in advance, am fairly new to rails. Creating a site to showcase cooking recipes, I have a functional test for my home page and my recipe page and both are failing. Annoyingly they used to pass, then i did "something" and now they fail. It looks like the tests aren't able to load the fixtures somehow.

Focussing purely on the "should get show" test from the recipe resource, the test that fails is here;

```
class RecipesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do 
    @recipe = recipes(:spag_bol)
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show, :id => @recipe.to_param

    assert_not_nil assigns(:recipe)
    assert_equal @recipe.name, assigns(:page_title)
    assert_tag :h1, :content => assigns(:page_title)
    assert_tag :p, :content => @recipe.excerpt

    assert_tag :h2, :content => "Ingredients"
    assert_select "#ingredients li", @recipe.ingredients.lines.count

    assert_tag :h2, :content => "Method"
    assert_select "#method li", @recipe.method.lines.count

    assert_template :show
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

fixture for this test is here;

```
spag_bol:
  id: 1
  name: "Spaghetti Bolognaise"
  excerpt: "Test test test."
  serves: "2"
  preparation_time: "30 minutes"
  cooking_time: "1 hour"
  method: "Test test test\ntest test test."
  ingredients: "Test test test\ntest test test."
```

The fail isn't actually a fail, it's an error;

```
RecipesControllerTest:
    ERROR should get show (0.02s) 
          ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
          /Users/Laura/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
```

It looks very much like the test isn't loading the fixture - can anyone enlighten me as to why?

## EDIT (EXPLANATION OF SOLUTION)

Rather than actual code, I used to just have links to my git repo above. As Ryan points out below, if I link to the master branch then it's going to be no good to someone in a few weeks time if they find this question, so the links are gone and have been replaced by code. Ironically, doing this demonstrates precisely where i was going wrong! I was convinced that it was the following line in the test that was causing the problem;

```
assert_equal @recipe.name, assigns(:page_title)
```

Because that's the only one that references a "name" method, and the error message very much made it look like the fixture wasn't bringing back a recipe. In fact, it was, and the REAL error was actually being thrown by my index page because a CATEGORY didn't have a name. This wasn't happening when i actually ran the application because my dev environment has all this data filled in, which further convinced me that the problem was with the tests and not the code.

So, lesson learned: if it doesn't look like there is a problem with your functional tests then the error might be being thrown by your controllers or views for some other reason, unrelated to what you're trying to test.

Comment: The issue with posting code on GitHub is that you're linking to the master branch. Over time, this will change into something different and so it won't be super obvious what it was that was wrong in the first place. It's better to link to another branch or a specific ref that's not master so people can see it for historical reasons.

Comment: Agree with Ryan, keep in mind that Stack Overflow isn't just about getting an answer to your question but also about creating an archive of info for other people that may have the same problem as you in the future

Comment: Is there a bigger error message for that test failure? I can't get it to display on my machine.

Comment: @Ryan - thank you for clearing that up, will tidy up the post in the morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your recipe fixture is not setting up any categories. When it attempts to render `app/views/recipes/show.html.erb`, it calls the `comma_separated_links_for` method which assumes that `@recipe.categories` is populated.

Inside this method, it calls `pop` on it which gets the latest element in this array. Because there's no categories, this returns `nil`.

Later on, around line 10 in this method, you attempt to call `name` on `nil`, which results in your test failing.

To fix this, assign a category to the recipe fixture. I've not used fixtures in a very, very long time, so I cannot advise on how to do this. I use things like [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) instead.

Comment: Ya I didn't dig in that far. I think you are right. Also factory_girl is way way way more pleasant than using fixtures. And I might also suggest [mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) and [rspec](http://rspec.info/) while you are at it

Comment: Thank you! I was looking in completely the wrong place. I think what I'll do is actually just change the "comma_seperated_links_for" method to handle lists with zero elements - thanks also for the tips on alternatives to fixtures, will check those out.

Comment: I guess it was lucky you had your app on GitHub after all :) Would have been difficult to track it down otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is running fine. Your application code is failing because it is trying to call a method on nil. This usually happens with controller logic errors or template typos. In your case you are assuming that you find a valid record in the first line of `recipes#show` so you go ahead and call the second line with, but you aren't passing a valid id in the test.

tl;dr: I think this:

```
test "should get show" do
  get :show, :id => @recipe.to_param
```

should be this:

```
test "should get show" do
  get :show, :id => @recipe.id
```

But I think the test is telling you there may be a larger issue that needs addressing...

Comment: Nope, this is not what's causing it. See my answer.